# What are the valid scriptural references for Hindus?

Tags: discussion

As per the sites policies, what are the valid references that can be used for authoritative answers to Hindu questions.

Comment: Not wikipedia, that's for sure :)

Comment: Maybe we need Hindupedia ;)

Comment: Hindupedia is an actual site